# Making a vector of superclass type that can store subclass objects

Tags: c++, oop, pointers, vector

So I started a small little project to work on while I am learning. Basically, what I'm trying to do is a small "game" which I plan to build on as I learn new things.

Here is a brief description and my problem.

Basically, I want to assign various Hero types to a player based on their choice.

I made a base class "Hero" with only a HP parameter so far. After that, I made 2 derived classes from Hero, HeroType1, HeroType2 which will have specific abilities and so on.

I decided on storing various hero types in `std::vector<Hero*> Heroes`. Basically, I start my "game" by calling initializeHeroes function which, depending on the player choice creates a new object of type NewHero1 or NewHero2 and stores it an the vector mentioned before. The thing is, no matter what I tried so far, I can't access derived member functions when I want to use them later, only those of the Hero class.

What feels like a good solution: declare global variables player1, player2 and assign to them after players choose the HeroType. However, I can't do that because the data type has to be known before compiling. Sorry if this is a stupid and basic question, my knowledge is still very limited and that is why I am asking for some hints here.

I'd kindly like to ask on how would you approach this, I know it is a very simple issue, but I'm still a beginner and I'm trying to figure out the best way to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Lookup the visitor pattern, for one solution. Other than that, your question doesn't fit the SO question format well.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to call a member function from a element from `std::vector<Hero*> Heroes` and you know somehow that this element points to a *Hero2*-type, then you could create a new temporary variable `Hero2 * tmpPtr` and set this variable to the element whose memberfunction you want to call (`tmpPtr = Heroes[i]`). Then you should be able to call a memberfunction like this: `tmpPtr->hero2Memberfuncion()`.

Full code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class SomeClass
{
public:
    void a() {
        std::cout << "a" << std::endl;
    }
};

class AnotherClass : public SomeClass
{
public:
    void b() {
        std::cout << "b" << std::endl;
    }
};

void main() {
    std::vector<SomeClass *> vec;
    AnotherClass v;
    vec.push_back(&v);

    AnotherClass * tmpPtr = (AnotherClass *)vec[0];
    tmpPtr->b(); //Output: "b"
}
```

However if you want for example loop through the whole vector and for every element run a memberfunction that has the same name but the body of that function differs depending on to what Hero-type the element points, then you may want to use *virtual* functions. Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class SomeClass
{
public:
    virtual void a() {
        std::cout << "from SomeClass" << std::endl;
    }
};

class AnotherClass : public SomeClass
{
public:
    void a() {
        std::cout << "from AnotherClass" << std::endl;
    }
};

void main() {
    std::vector<SomeClass *> vec;

    AnotherClass v1;
    vec.push_back(&v1);
    vec[0]->a(); //Output: "from AnotherClass"

    SomeClass v2;
    vec.push_back(&v2);
    vec[1]->a(); //Output: "from SomeClass"
}
```